# Is it possible to move Ruby code from the controller in to a '.js.rjs' file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, move

*I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and for a correct organization of my code I would like to have the whole AJAX code related to an action in a respectively 'action.js.rjs' file.*

For example, if I have code in a controller like this:

```
def action
  ...

  format.js {
    # BEGIN code to move in to the 'action.js.rjs' file
    responds_to_parent do
      ...
    end
    # END code to move in to the 'action.js.rjs' file
  }

end
```

is it possible to move in some way the 'responds_to_parent' statement or its content from the controller in to the 'action.js.rjs' file and make it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This should work:

```
    responds_to_parent do
      render :action => 'update.js.rjs'
    end
```